# C# GetProcAddress returns IntPtr.Zero with Error Code 126, upon loading exported method from successfully loaded C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++

I have two projects. One C# WinForms project that is my main program, and a C++ DLL project, with exported functions.

I am facing a problem, where `GetProcAddress` from my C# application returns invalid handle to the exported function from the C++ dll, with an error code `126`.

`LoadLibrary` doesn't return 0, meaning that the handle for the DLL should be valid. I've faced an issue with `LoadLibrary` as well, but I've resolved it by building both projects on x64 platform.

Why does `GetProcAddress` fail with code `126` though? (Specified module could not be found)

---

My `C#` project is WinForms using .NET Framework 4.7.2, and looks like this.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpLibFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProcAddress", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(int hModule,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpProcName);

int ModuleHandle = 0;

delegate int square_root(int i);
square_root FuncSquareRoot;

void BeginProgram() {

        ModuleHandle = LoadLibrary($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}MyLibrary.dll"); // Current folder path
        if (ModuleHandle == 0)
        {
            int last_err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            MessageBox.Show($"LoadLibrary: Error code ({last_err})", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        IntPtr iTemp = GetProcAddress(ModuleHandle, "square_root"); // Using dllexp.exe, this is the name shown for the exported function...
        if (iTemp == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int last_err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            MessageBox.Show($"GetProcAddress: Error code ({last_err})", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        FuncSquareRoot = (square_root)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(iTemp, typeof(square_root));
}
```

My C++ project is an exported functions DLL project, using C++17, and looks like this:

**MyLibrary.h**

```
#ifdef MYLIB_EXPORTS
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

MYLIB_API int square_root(int i);
```

**MyLibrary.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "MyLibrary.h"

#include <math.h>

// This is an example of an exported function.
MYLIB_API int square_root(int i) {

    return static_cast<int>(sqrt(static_cast<double>(i)));
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `LoadLibrary` instead of just `[DllImport("MyLibrary.dll"` ? Note that for any kind of complex API I would use C++/CLI instead of messing around with P/Invoke. Especially if I was the author of both libraries.

Comment: C++ mangles the names of functions. Try using `extern "C"` as well as `MYLIB_API`

Comment: `GetProcAddress` requires ASCII / SBCS, exported names never use Unicode.  Set `CharSet` on the p/invoke declaration, as shown on pinvoke.net: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getprocaddress.

Comment: `hModule` parameter of `GetProcAddress` must be `IntPtr` not `int`.  The difference is critical on the `x64` platform.  Again, this is correctly shown in pinvoke.net

Comment: Return type from `LoadLibrary` also must be `IntPtr` not `int`, and that too is correctly shown on pinvoke.net: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/LoadLibrary.html

Comment: Using dllexp.exe was not helping you, it demangles exported function names to show their original source code declaration.  Instead favor running dumpbin.exe /exports from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  You'll also need correct pinvoke declarations and the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer] attribute on the delegate to declare it Cdecl.

Comment: @JonasH I'll give it a try as my last option, if everything else fails...

Comment: @RichardCritten Nope, that doesn't work.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand. Thanks for the useful information. I had no idea VS had its own...

Comment: @RichardCritten I just realized what you meant with your solution! I was supposed to use extern "C" to enclose the `MYLIB_API` macros as well, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The handle for the DLL was valid, until you tried to store it into a 32-bit integer.

Use the correct p/invoke declarations shown on pinvoke.net

- https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/LoadLibrary.html
- https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetProcAddress.html

Comment: I've implemented those invokes instead. Now I'm getting an error code `127` (The specified procedure could not be found.) with `GetProcAddress`.